# Adding the sum of table cells using jQuery and inputing the sum in a row cell at the bottom of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, I primarily do marketing these days. All the programming I know has been self taught so go easy on me :).

I have a 4 tables that are dynamically created using Drupal views. The tables are presented with jQuery ui-tabs. The last cell in each table row contains a number. What I am trying to do is add up each cells numbers and create another row at the bottom of the table that outputs the sum of the cells.

I wrote a JS function to achieve this more than a year ago and it was working fine but now it is not. Something in the markup must have changed with a Drupal/module update and now it is not working. When I wrote this small script I was doing more programming than I ever planned on and was in the groove, but now I have lost it and I am a little lost. Attached is an image of what I am trying to accomplish.[image]

and here is my markup and script. I am using jQuery v3.2.1 No errors in my console.

Thanks for your help.

```html
<div class="blocktabs click default ui-tabs ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="blocktabs-docent_time">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header" role="tablist">
    <li aria-controls="blocktabs-docent_time-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="true" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0">
      <a class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#blocktabs-docent_time-1" id="ui-id-5" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">This Month</a>
    </li>
    <li aria-controls="blocktabs-docent_time-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" role="tab" tabindex="-1">
      <a class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#blocktabs-docent_time-2" id="ui-id-6" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">Last Month</a>
    </li>
    <li aria-controls="blocktabs-docent_time-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" aria-selected="false" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" role="tab" tabindex="-1">
      <a class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#blocktabs-docent_time-3" id="ui-id-7" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">2 Months Ago</a>
    </li>
    <li aria-controls="blocktabs-docent_time-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" aria-selected="false" class="ui-tabs-tab ui-corner-top ui-state-default ui-tab" role="tab" tabindex="-1">
      <a class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#blocktabs-docent_time-4" id="ui-id-8" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">This Year</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="blocktabs-docent_time-1" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="view view-docent-time view-id-docent_time view-display-id-block_1">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" id="view-field-time-date-table-column" scope="col">Date</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-type" id="view-type-table-column" scope="col">Type</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" id="view-term-node-tid-table-column" scope="col">Task</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" id="view-field-v-hours-table-column" scope="col">Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column">2018-12-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column">Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column">Whalers Cabin</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column">6.5</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="blocktabs-docent_time-2" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">
    <div class="view view-docent-time view-id-docent_time view-display-id-block_2">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" id="view-field-time-date-table-column--2" scope="col">Date</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-type" id="view-type-table-column--2" scope="col">Type</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" id="view-term-node-tid-table-column--2" scope="col">Task</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" id="view-field-v-hours-table-column--2" scope="col">Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--2">2018-11-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--2">Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--2">Whalers Cabin</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--2">8.0</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="blocktabs-docent_time-3" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">
    <div class="view view-docent-time view-id-docent_time view-display-id-block_3">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" id="view-field-time-date-table-column--3" scope="col">Date</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-type" id="view-type-table-column--3" scope="col">Type</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" id="view-term-node-tid-table-column--3" scope="col">Task</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" id="view-field-v-hours-table-column--3" scope="col">Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--3">2018-10-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--3">Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--3">Scoping</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--3">5.5</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-8" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" id="blocktabs-docent_time-4" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">
    <div class="view view-docent-time view-id-docent_time view-display-id-block_4">
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" id="view-field-time-date-table-column--4" scope="col">Date</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-type" id="view-type-table-column--4" scope="col">Type</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" id="view-term-node-tid-table-column--4" scope="col">Task</th>
                <th class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" id="view-field-v-hours-table-column--4" scope="col">Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--4">2018-10-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--4">Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--4">Scoping</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--4">5.5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--4">2018-12-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--4">Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--4">Whalers Cabin</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--4">6.5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--4">2018-11-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--4">Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--4">Whalers Cabin</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--4">8.0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--4">2018-01-02</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--4">Non-Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--4">Monthly Docent Meeting</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--4">2.0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-time-date" headers="view-field-time-date-table-column--4">2018-02-07</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-type" headers="view-type-table-column--4">Non-Public Time</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-term-node-tid" headers="view-term-node-tid-table-column--4">Administration</td>
                <td class="views-field views-field-field-v-hours" headers="view-field-v-hours-table-column--4">6.5</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
(function($) {
  
  
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    
    function totalTime($vars) {
      var $timeRecord = $vars.find('table tbody tr td:last-child');
      var $lasttableRow = $vars.find('table tbody tr').last();
      var totalTime = 0;
      $timeRecord.each(function () {
        totalTime += parseFloat($(this).text());
      });
      $lasttableRow.after('<tr><td><strong>TOTAL</strong></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>' + totalTime + '</strong></td></tr>')
    }
    
    if ($('#blocktabs-docent_time').length) {
      totalTime($('#blocktabs-docent_time-1'));
      totalTime($('#blocktabs-docent_time-2'));
      totalTime($('#blocktabs-docent_time-3'));
      totalTime($('#blocktabs-docent_time-4'));
    }
            
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: @jpshayes, it is working as expected, issue is that you have only one record in every tab, i just added one more record in first tab for testing- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aPNpdE

Comment: Yes I have checked my console, I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @NagaSaiA, weird, I added an additional record to all the tables and it is still not working. No errors in my console.

Comment: Seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2dzeysv3/

Comment: @j08691 shoot, It must be something else in my environment causing it to fail. Thanks for your help.